# How do you insure that Derived2 destructor is called?

Tags: c++, destructor

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Base
{
    public:
        Base ( )
        {
            cout << "Inside Base constructor" << endl;
        }

        ~Base ( )
        {
            cout << "Inside Base destructor" << endl;
        }

};

class Derived : public Base
{
    public:    
        Derived  ( )
        {
        cout << "Inside Derived constructor" << endl;
        }

        ~Derived ( )
        {
            cout << "Inside Derived destructor" << endl;
        }
};

class Derived2 : public Base
{
    public:
        static void bogus(Derived2* d)
        {
            cout << "bogus" << endl;
        }

        Derived2  ( )
        {
            cout << "Inside Derived2 constructor" << endl;
        }

        ~Derived2 ( )
        {
            cout << "Inside Derived2 destructor" << endl;
        }
};

int main( )
{
    Derived y;
    Derived2::bogus( new Derived2 ());

    return 0;
}
```

-

```
>Inside Base constructor
>Inside Derived constructor
>Inside Base constructor
>Inside Derived2 constructor
>bogus
>Inside Derived destructor
>Inside Base destructor
>Press <RETURN> to close this window...
```

I was testing some stuff and found this weird behavior. How come the destructor is not called when we create an object inside the parameter field? Is there any solution, is it even needed, is there memory leak?

Comment: Well the program will hold on to the object until it goes out of scope, and even then the garbage collector seems to pass at random times. The destructor should definitely get called, the question is when. Also, you're `Derived2` is static, this will keep it alive for the life of the program I believe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all - when you're making classes derive from one another, you should make sure the destructors are `virtual`. If you don't, you may have memory leaks when the deriving classes have additional members:

```
virtual ~Base ( )
{
  cout << "Inside Base destructor" << endl;
}
```

Secondly - when you allocate memory using `new`, the destructor won't be called on the created object, untill you manually delete it with `delete`:

```
int main( )
{
  Derived y;
  Derived2 *ptr = new Derived2();
  Derived2::bogus(ptr);
  delete ptr;
  return 0;
}
```

If you're unsure on **when** to delete the object, use `std::shared_ptr` or delete it inside the destructor of the class taking it as the parameter. Note that `shared_ptr` is available only for C++11, if you're using an older version (like still many people are), try using the **boost** library.

Comment: "when you're making classes derive from one another, you have to make sure the destructors are virtual" -- no you don't. Nor is it a good idea to do that in *all* classes you derive from.

Comment: @jalf could you explain this? in my understanding there is no way around virtual destructors in polymorph classes

Comment: @vlad_tepesch: first, the question was not about polymorphic classes. Nothing else in those classes is virtual. Second, the virtual destructor is only important if you might call `delete` on a pointer to the *base* class. If you don't do that, everything is fine, and your classes will work just fine.

Comment: @PawełStawarz no, not really. It's just superstition. You should use virtual destructors when you *need* to use them and because you understand *why* they're needed in that situaiton. Not just because "I heard a rumor that bad things can happen otherwise".

Comment: why does the destructor gets called even if I don't use delete?

Comment: @user3435009 when you create an object with `new`, you have to `delete`. If you just create the object in a normal way, the garbage collector calls the destructor when needed (so most often - when the current scope ends).

Comment: @jalf whenever you design a polymorph base class you can neve know if somewhere in the inheritance hierarchy needs to be destructed. so you always have to define a virtual destructor since its not possible later anymore

Comment: @PawełStawarz C++ does not (yet) contain a garbage collector.

Comment: @manni66 C++ offers implicit memory management for objects created on the stack. That's what garbage collection is all about, so there __is__ a garbage collector. It's not as powerful as it could be, and isn't the same as in - for example - Java, but due to its function, the name is still valid.

Answer (score 1):

You do not create an object inside the parameter field. You create an object on the free store (aka heap). You have to call delete to destroy it. For everey new there has to be a delete. There is a memory leak!

Comment: why does the destructors gets called even though I did not use delete explicitly?

Comment: You posted the output of a destructor call to Derived, that is stack allocated. There is no output from Derived2.

Answer (score 1):

Whatever created by `new` needs to be `delete`. Here you are creating temp object. Try to create before passing to function. Also make `base` `destructor` `virtual`.

```
int main( )
{

  Derived y;
  Derived2 *d2 = new Derived2();
  Derived2::bogus( d2);

  delete d2;

  return 0;
}
```